# Do not give users a choice to open a deeplink in chrome

Tags: android, cordova, deep-linking

I have a deeplink set on my Android app in Cordova:

```
<universal-links>
    <host scheme="https" name="example.com">
        <path url="/google-log-in" />
    </host>
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />
</universal-links>
```

It works just fine - but when I click on a link in the browser for the first time which matches my `name`, it gives the user a choice:

[image]

Can I make it so that the user will never have the choice to open it in Chrome? Because if they open it in Chrome, they will never be able to log into my app.